# Effect of moving conductor on drift velocity of electrons

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, kinematics, electric-circuits

The question is a bit trivial, but due to not much familiarity with electromagnetism and all, I would like to have it cleared from you all.

I have a current carrying circuit and there is wire which is the part of the circuit and can move freely (imagine a wire on two metallic rails connected to a circuit). Also I have a uniform magnetic field set up. This would lead wire to move (suppose it does, keeping in mind the direction of field and all). Now,I was wondering that whether this velocity of the wire would lead to a component being added to the old velocities of electrons moving in the wire, and thus ultimately changing the drift velocity of electrons and that would lead to change in how the wire experiences the magnetic force due to the magnetic field present.

I am unable to find any issued with this change in drift velocity of electrons when the conductor is moving, but not too sure about it and wanted to confirm this.

So I would request you to see this and tell me if I am wrong somewhere. Also I would be delighted to know whether there is an experiment which sheds light on this or is related to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a circuit with something like a rail-gun geometry? Don't see how the net force on the wire would change due to its motion down the rail since the resulting v x B forces would act on both the negative and positive charges in the wire, and the wire is electrically neutral.

Comment: @Samuel Weir I am not aware of rail gun geometry. You may take the case of any conductor moving wherein current is flowing. Now will the velocity of conductor effect the drift velocity of electrons and in turn how they feel the magnetic force?